# How can i generate snort log file in a text human readable format?

Tags: logging, file-format, non-ascii-characters, logfile, snort

When i use this command:

## snort -l /home/username/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs -d

OR :

## snort -l /home/username/snort-2.9.9.0/snort_logs -b

It log packets in Ascii file format,

I want the log files in a text readable format. What command should i use to log packet in text format? and what configuration i need to add to the snort.cong file to do the required ?

Thanks

Comment: Option '-l' make pcap format log. if u connecting snort to db, snort make hexadecimal format log in db.

Comment: I want conncet snort to hadoop mapreduce and then count the packet , So what file format should i use ? and what is the right log command ?

Comment: Read this document: http://hortonworks.com/blog/big-data-security-part-one-introducing-packetpig/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert snort log file from pcap format to text format we use :
(tcpdump tool) or (Tshark tool) as following :

## tcpdump -n -tttt -r /snortLogFilePath/snortLogFileName > /pathToStoreAt/anyName.txt

OR:

## tshark -r /snortLogFilePath/snortLogFileName > /pathToStoreAt/anyName.txt